# Recommendation needed for cross platform authentication .net core MVC and Xamarin

Tags: authentication, .net-core, xamarin.android

I need to create an application (Mobile) and a Web application. It needs to use the same database so the same user authentication is required.

Can anyone give me such a demo or an idea where to begin.

I have looked into identity but I see that it is not compatible with Xamarin.

Expected result would be a cross platform login provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my recommendation is to create one web service that can connect to the db and your mobile app and web app make http get/post calls to the web service.  This also means you get to keep db logic in one place instead of duplicated across the applications.

The web app and mobile app should get some kind of authorization token (such as bearer) from the webservice to ensure no ones else is hitting the api.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful, do you have any recommendations of 3rd party libraries to use something like identity that would work in .net core web api?

Comment: I use OWIN OAuth (not 3rd party.)